# How to watch for ngSwitchCase in Ionic 2 / Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angularjs-ng-switch

I have a simple `ngSwitchCase`  [scenario](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/segment/Segment/)

I want to watch for and get notified of `ngSwitchCase` in the controller, Basically when i switch between tabs.

Any ideas?

Comment: ```ionChange```
expression to evaluate when a segment button has been changed

Comment: answer on your question can be found by link which your provided yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/segment/Segment/) I see there is an output event called `ionChange`. You could hook into that:

```html
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedTab" (ionChange)="selectedTabChanged($event)">
    ...
<ion-segment>
```

And in your component you then have your method:

```ts
selectedTabChanged($event): void {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: what about angular 2?

Comment: `ionChange` works, i guess it can be used in all other instances

Comment: @rinukkusu try `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"` or `(change)="onChange(item.value)"`